# Ng-view or ui-view not displaying html page

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am relatively new to Angularjs, and am building a website. When I try to inject **todo.html** into the body tags of **index.html** nothing happens. I am not getting any errors in the console. I have read many of the similar posts to mine, and have already tried

- **Remove the ng-include from the body of index.html**
- **Moved the links for angualrjs and bootstrap from the body of index.html to the head**
- **Originally I used Ng-route but it did not work,  so I implemented ui-router**

I have tried both ng-route and ui-router,and both run without any errors. I don't think it has anything to do with either.

**index.html**

```
    <html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
    <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

    <title>Todo App</title>
    <!-- Angular ans JS links-->
    <script src="vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/todo.service.js"></script>       
    <script src="app/controllers/todo.controller.js"></script>

     <!-- <script src="vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>-->

    <!--Jquery and Bootstrap Links-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- css links  -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- load bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/todoApp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/Header-Picture.css">
</head>
<body >

    <div ng-include="'app/views/header.html'"></div>


    <!--<div ng-include="'app/views/footer.view.html'"></div>
    -->
    <ui-view></ui-view>
   <!--<div ui-view></div>-->
  </body>
  </html>
```

**App.js**

```
var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', [
    'ui.router'
]);
todoApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('todo', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'views/todo.html',
        controller: 'TodoController'
    })});
```

**todo.controller.js**

```
todoApp.controller('TodoController', ['$scope', 'Todos', function TodoController($scope, Todos) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    console.log("in the TodoController");
    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
    Todos.get()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
    });

    // when submitting the add form, send the text to the spring API
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        if(!$scope.todoForm.$valid) {
            return;
        }
        Todos.create($scope.formData)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
            $scope.todos.push(data);
        });
    };

    // delete a todo after checking it
    $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        Todos.delete(id)
        .success(function(data) {
            angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo, index){
                if(todo.id == id) {
                    $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    $scope.saveTodo = function(todo) {
        Todos.update(todo)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.editedTodo = {};
        });
    };

    $scope.editedTodo = {};

    $scope.editTodo = function(todo) {
        $scope.editedTodo = todo;
    }

    $scope.revertTodo = function() {
        $scope.editedTodo = {};
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Why your url is empty. You should use otherwise instead of "/". And I guess this is your problem

Comment: Could write a jsFiddle with this code?

Comment: Did you define TodoController

Comment: I have edited the question to include the controller, I had it defined from the start.  @salih şenol çakarcı

Comment: how about moving your scripts before closing </body> tag

Comment: Originally that is were I had them placed, and I moved after reading a similar post to my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using otherwise to force the first state to be loaded as below

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('todo', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'todo.html',

    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Your index.html will look like

```
<div ng-include="'app/views/header.html'"></div>   
     <ui-view>

     </ui-view>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kZlyonQAU1CewTfH77zu?p=preview)**

Comment: is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have added your code to my project but, it still is not working.

Comment: Yes. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http:localhost:8080/todo.html

Comment: And Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$compile/tpload?p0=todo.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:18640
    at angular.js:15627
    at m.$eval (angular.js:16895)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:16711)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17003)
    at g (angular.js:11324)
    at x (angular.js:11522)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (angular.js:11463)

Comment: do u have team viewer?

Comment: No and i have never used it either

Comment: @Sean Correct the path of the todo.html

Comment: this is the current path: templateUrl: 'views/todo.html'

Answer (score 0):

I added the code posted by @Aravind to my project which I belive was an improvement on my own and was correct. But the issue was the file path to the todo.html. The file path in the original was **views/todo.html**
the correct path is **app/views/todo.html**

**My original code:**

```
todoApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('todo', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'views/todo.html',
        controller: 'TodoController'
    })});
```

**Current Working Code**

```
todoApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('todo', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'app/views/todo.html',

    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```